# Python 2 vs Python 3 dictionary keys order

Tags: python

Consider a simple script with the following code:

```
d = {'asdf': 1, 'qwer': 2}
for v in d.keys():
    print(v)
```

This seems to be deterministic (i.e.: the keys are always printed in the same order in all executions) when executed with a Python 2 interpreter (2.7.10), but not when executed with a Python 3 interpreter (3.5.0).

Could anybody explain what changed?

I know a dictionary is a hash table and, therefore, the keys are sorted "arbitrarily". However, I thought they were not sorted randomly (i.e.: when creating the same dictionary again, it would have the same representation in memory and the `.keys()` method will return the keys in the same exact arbitrary order.

Also, the Python documentation states (for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)):

> Keys and values are listed (Python 2)/iterated over (Python 3) in an arbitrary order which is non-random[...]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I also find the same thing, using python 2.7.10 and python 3.5.1. Sometimes, when I check a dict is same in a  test case, usingl str(a_dict)=="{'asdf': 1, 'qwer': 2}". But in 3.5.1, sometimes, it pass, sometimes fails.